# Settings object has no attribute screen_height?

Tags: python

settings.py:

```
class Settings():
    def __int__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230,230,230)
```

try.py:

```
from settings import Settings
ai_settings=Settings() 
print(ai_settings.screen_height)
```

I execute try.py,
why tell me
"Settings object has no attribute screen_height"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `__init__` as `__int__`, which meant that your constructor wasn't being called when you created an instance of the `Settings` class, because it had the wrong name.

Change `def __int__(self):` to `def __init__(self):` so that Python sees your class' constructor.

Comment: I'm ashamed that I made a low error.
Thanks for your help

Comment: @huwei Don't be! Everybody makes mistakes, and the more you practise, the less you make.

Comment: I'll remember your words and try my best.Thanks